# Filter (no display) layers in GeoExt.LegendPanel with names LIKE some pattern

Tags: filter, openlayers-2, legend, geoext

This works to avoid Basemap layers such as Google Maps and overlays such as WMS to appear in the GeoExt Legend Panel:

```
var legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    border: false,
    filter: function(record){
        if(!(record.getLayer().isBaseLayer) && (record.getLayer() instanceof OpenLayers.Layer.WMS)){
        return true;
        }
    } });
```

The problem is that I need to filter (ie. no display) layers with names having "beam" in their names, I tried with no success this:

```
return record.getLayer().displayInLayerSwitcher == false && record.getLayer().name == '%beam%';
return record.getLayer().displayInLayerSwitcher == false &&
record.get("layer").name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
return record.get("layer").name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
```

Comment: Why did you surround the keyword with `%` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the "%". Use

```
return record.getLayer().name.indexOf("beam") == -1;
```

instead of

```
return record.getLayer().name.indexOf("%beam%") == -1;
```